# Does Earth Intel shown at the end of a mission matter?

Tags: strike-suit-zero

At the end of a mission, you get an Earth Intel reports that either says the Colonial forces have been strengthened or weakened. What determines the result you get and does it influence anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is entirely determined by which medal you earned: Bronze or Silver medals give you a bad result, and Gold or Platinum medals give you a good result. Bad results are things like "Earth's infrastructure heavily damaged", or "the damage from your raids is negligible". Good results are things like "Earth's infrastructure barely scratched", or "your raids leave deep and lasting damage to the Colonials." Whether you complete the bonus mission or not does not affect the Earth Intel.

**The number of good and bad results you get from missions affects the ending:** with enough good results, the epilogue is positive. If you just go through the game and don't replay missions, you'll probably get a bad epilogue; it's much easier to earn Gold Medals when you go back to the first few missions with Fire And Forget Missiles and the Strike Suit. I recommend seeing the bad ending, then getting better medals on early missions so you can see both endings.